# SQL : Query with multiple COUNT() and Specific Conditions

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and I've been trying to query a table where I need multiple `COUNT()` with specific conditions, those being:

- Distinct name in the `Name` Column
- Based on `Date`
- Based on a group

Here's a sample of the table:

| Group | Name | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GR1 | Name1 | 2022-01-01 |
| GR1 | Name1 | 2022-01-01 |
| GR1 | Name2 | 2022-02-01 |
| GR1 | Name3 | 2022-02-01 |
| GR2 | Name4 | 2022-01-01 |
| GR2 | Name5 | 2022-03-01 |
| GR2 | Name5 | 2022-03-01 |
| GR2 | Name6 | 2022-04-01 |
| GR2 | Name7 | 2022-04-01 |

And here's what i'm trying to achieve based on the sample:

| Month | GR1 | GR2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-03-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-04-01 | 0 | 2 |

Here's the query I've got so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Dates` AS Month,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `Name`) FROM `table` WHERE `Group` LIKE '%GR1%') AS GR1,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `Name`) FROM `table` WHERE `Group` LIKE '%GR2%') AS GR2 
FROM `table`
ORDER BY Month
```

I've got the result I expected from this where i got the number of distinct names but it's not filtered through the dates.

Result:

| DATE | GR1 | GR2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-04-01 | 3 | 4 |

I've been struggling to create the condition for the dates while keeping the condition for the Groups

Thanks in advance for any tips or answers you might have!
Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting *distinct* rows you need to aggregate by the date and use *conditional aggregation* to count your group names.

What your query is trying to do won't work since each *subquery* is looking at all rows, you are not *correlating* to within the date ranges.

Try the following:

```
select dates as "Month", 
    Count(distinct case when "group" = 'GR1' then Name end) GR1,
    Count(distinct case when "group" = 'GR2' then Name end) GR2
from t
group by dates;
```